# Navigating directly to URL in Single Page Node App Results in 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, static

I have a NodeJS backend hooked up to a ReactJS frontend (not using create-react-app).

I'm bundling the React frontend and the Node backend with webpack. The output for the webpack config creates a "dist" directory in the root directory of my application folder. Inside the "dist" directory I have the bundled server.js file and a "public" directory that holds the index.html, and bundled .js/.css files.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
dist
- server.js
- public
-- index.html
-- client.{hash}.js
-- client.{hash}.css
```

(hash above is replaced with the hash generated by Webpack).

I start the server by running `NODE_ENV='production' node ./dist/server.js`. This will log an open port in my terminal (for example: 60245) and when I navigate to localhost:{PORT} my app runs and the default route built with React Router v4 loads, for example: `localhost:{PORT}/pages/dashboard if the user is authenticated`.

The problem is, if I go directly to a URL (for example: localhost:{PORT}/pages/dashboard) I get a 404 response and see `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/dist/public/index.html'` in my terminal.

After quite a bit of Googling, I add the conditional below:

```
app.use(express.static('dist/public'));
app.use('/api', routes);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/public/index.html'));
  });
} else {
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/public/index.html'));
  });
}
```

When running the app in development mode, I'm able to go directly to a URL without issue. This only happens when running the app in production.

The file structure for the whole application looks like this:

```
config
-- webpack
--- webpack.dev.config.js
--- webpack.prod.config.js
-- tests
dist
- server.js
- public
-- index.html
-- client.{hash}.js
-- client.{hash}.css
node_modules
src
- client
-- {all client stuff}
- server 
-- {all server stuff}
{config files}
```

In development, I only bundle the react front end and not the server, and I'm using Webpack dev server to serve up the React frontend and I'm proxying the backend server served with nodemon, and I'm building out to an in memory "dist" folder in the same location, which is why the non-production sendFile method is going up a couple of directories.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't have an answer for you but kudos for very well documented question/problem

Comment: I appreciate that! I was lost and was hoping the most information possible would help, but I was ultimately able to find the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the actual issue is, which was related to webpack rather than with node_env, etc. See here for more info: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1599.

For posterity, the fix was to add

```
node: {
  __dirname: false
}
```

to my wepack.prod config because webpack seems to change the root for __dirname on compile.

I then updated my path to the static index.html file to

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
```

And suddenly all paths work!

TL;DR add

```
node: {
  __dirname: false
}
```

to webpack config if you're compiling the server code, too.

Answer (score 0):

just take a look at the result of the path.join, and see for yourself if it's the right path. put this in your server's code: `console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/public/index.html'))`

Comment: I appreciate the response, you comment helped lead me to the answer!